# Get Rounded Corner in Maximized Windows in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Gnome Shell 3.36.4.

The titlebar of my windows, when unmaximized, have rounded corners.[image: unmaximized window]

But when I maximize the window, the rounded corner disappears.

[image: maximized window]

How can I get rounded corners in maximized windows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any different theme?

I'm not sure whether this can be changed manually, however my Gnome has rounded (top) corners even when maximized. It seems version 3.38 has this by default, or perhaps it's the theme I'm currently using. Something I wish is to also have rounded corners at the bottom.

Here a couple print screen unmaximized / maximized. I have a big monitor; I hope this print screen can show them as rounded corners.

The theme I'm using: Prof-Gnome-Dark3.6

ps: I'm running manjaro currently (multi boot) so I guess this is why I have a newer version.

[image: unmaximized]
[image: maximized]